# Multiple Repositories on HttpGet C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using the Repository pattern with.NETCORE and am trying to return data back from an HttpGet request. The data I want back is from multiple un-related tables in SQL. I am trying to wrap my head around being able to retrieve the data from each respective repository and return an object with all data. I hope this makes sense, I am stuck and started to go down "Unit of Work" but can't find a good example that does what I would like, query multiples in un-related tables from one get request. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use your entity repositories to bring the data into your controller method then combine into a viewmodel and return.

Comment: Ahh viewmodel, I was just trying to create an object and assign each value to a property of that object. Thanks I'll give that a shot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1.** Create model classes (domain model layer) for each table / view or the dataset that comes from the SQL database. Shown below:

```
public class DataFromTable1
{
        // properties mapped with the sql table columns
}

public class DataFromTable2
{
    // properties mapped with the sql table columns
}

public class DataFromTable3
{
    // properties mapped with the sql table columns
}
```

**Step 2.** Write data access classes that will call the SQL database (stored proc or direct SQLstatement – I don’t recommend direct table access from .net though) to populate your model classes created in step 1. You can use any repository pattern in this step.

**Step 3.** Create a view model class that will wrap the model classes with its properties and hydrate them by calling the data access class create in step 2. Generally view model classes are created under the MVC project.

```
public class MyViewModelClass
{
    public DataFromTable1 DataFromTable1 { get; set; }
    public DataFromTable2 DataFromTable2 { get; set; }
    public DataFromTable3 DataFromTable3 { get; set; }
}
```

**Step 4.** Use this view model to display the data in the view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So how would I instaniate a new "myviewmodelclass" basically this will be responding to a http request and return data for my angular front end to consume

Comment: you can new up myviewmodelclass in the controller action. Populate its properties with the corresponding data types from the data access layer and return myviewmodelclass object. If its a json result that you want then use return Json(myviewmodelclass, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: this sounds like the best thing I've seen so far. I'll give this a shot and report back. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @YawarMurtaza if you're using MVC API you don't even need to do the "return Json(myviewmodelclass)" as the API controller will allow you to return the object type instead and then when calling the API you can specify if you want it as JSON, XML, etc in the call and the framework can handle that for you.